# AWS Glue job bookmark produces duplicates for csv files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

We receive 1 csv file everyday  in s3 bucket from our vendor at 11am. 
I convert this file into parquet format using Glue at 11:30am.

I've enabled job bookmark to not process already processed files.
Nonetheless, I see some files are being reprocessed thus creating duplicates.

I read these questions and answers [AWS Glue Bookmark produces duplicates for PARQUET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374622/aws-glue-bookmark-produces-duplicates) and [AWS Glue Job Bookmarking explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529192/aws-glue-job-bookmarking)

They gave good understanding of job bookmarking, but still do not address the issue.

AWS documentation says, it supports CSV files for bookmarking [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html).

Wondering if someone help me understand what could be the problem and if possible solution as well :)

Edit:

Pasting sample code here as requested by Prabhakar.

```
staging_database_name = "my-glue-db"
s3_target_path = "s3://mybucket/mydata/"


"""
 'date_index': date location in the file name
 'date_only': only date column is inserted
 'date_format': format of date
 'path': sub folder name in master bucket
"""

#fouo classified files
tables_spec = {
'sample_table': {'path': 'sample_table/load_date=','pkey': 'mykey', 'orderkey':'myorderkey'}
}

spark_conf = SparkConf().setAll([
  ("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption", "true"),
  ("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId", kms_key_id)
])
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

for table_name, spec in tables_spec.items():
    datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=database_name,
                                                                table_name=table_name,
                                                                transformation_ctx='datasource0')

    resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame=datasource0, choice="make_struct", transformation_ctx='resolvechoice2')

    # Create spark data frame with input_file_name column
    delta_df = resolvechoice2.toDF().withColumn('ingest_datetime', lit(str(ingest_datetime)))

    date_dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(delta_df, glueContext, "date_dyf")
    master_folder_path1 = os.path.join(s3_target_path, spec['path']).replace('\\', '/')

    master_folder_path=master_folder_path1+load_date
    datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=date_dyf,
                                                            connection_type='s3',
                                                            connection_options={"path": master_folder_path},
                                                            format='parquet', transformation_ctx='datasink4')
job.commit()
```

Comment: Do you have `Job.init()` and `Job.commit()` in your code?

Comment: Yes, I do have job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args) & job.commit() in my code.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have set transformation_ctx for all of your Glue transformations as mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html and also share your script here

Comment: Code is simple, I convert csv files into parquet. I've attached sample code in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke to AWS Support engineer and she mentioned that, she is able to reproduce the issue and have raised it with Glue technical team for resolution.

Nonetheless, I couldn't wait on them fixing the bug and have taken different approach.

Solution:

1. Disable Glue bookmark
2. After Glue job converts csv file to Parquet, I
   move csv file to different location in S3 bucket.